# No permission to read dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, windows-10

Working with pandas dataframes, i've been getting an error that I haven't been able to solve.

My code goes like:

```
to_do = Path(r"E:\\directory1\\directory2\\directory3\\To do\\")
to_compare = Path(r"E:\\directory1\\To compare\\")
# There are other directories here like the year and, inside it, the months
dfs1 = (read_dfs_1(path) for path in to_do.iterdir())
AR3, E3, E7 = read_lots()
dict_dfs1 = {working_month(p): p for p in dfs1}
dfs2 = (read_comparing_df(path, AR3, E3, E7) for path in to_compare.iterdir())
dict_dfs2= {working_month(p): p for p in dfs2}
```

No problems with dict_dfs1 but dict_dfs2 returns this error:

```
*** PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\directory1\\To compare\\2021'
```

I do have access to the directory;
There's no one else using the file;
The file is not marked as "read only"...

If I read the file manually, it reads with no problems.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The message:

```
*** PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\directory1\\To compare\\2021'
```

Tells you that you are trying to open a directory like if it were a file.

You may want to change it to something like this:

```
dfs1 = (read_dfs_1(path) for path in to_do.iterdir() if path.is_file())
```

Same applies to the second iterator:

```
dfs2 = (read_comparing_df(path, AR3, E3, E7) for path in to_compare.iterdir() if path.is_file())
```

It is not clear if you intend to perform a recursive iteration. If that's the case then the previous code will not work as it will exclude all directories.

Comment: It kinda worked.
You see, I don't get the error messenge anymore but than the dictionary is comming empty.
I realized that when I use `.iterdir()`, it only search paths in that specific directory.
I worked around the problem by using `.glob("**/*.xlsx")`. This will search for anything that ends with .xlsx inside the directory including subdirectories.
But that's another problem. The main issue I had was solved thanks to you.